# F# duplicate of Linux tac function (tac is opposite of cat)

Tags: .net, f#, f#-interactive

I’m struggling for quite a while now with this problem. I don’t understand how to read line from a file from the end and make function take 1 or 2 file paths( 2nd must be optional)
Any suggestions...

```
let checkIfExists path = 
      if System.IO.File.Exists path 
      then true
      else false
let tac path = 
      if checkIfExists path =
      then
            System.IO.File.ReadAllLines |> Seq.rev
            0
      else
            printfn “no such file exists”
            -1
```

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? If so, remember that it's important to tell your professor who helped you with the assignment, so that he/she can see what you were able to understand and what you struggled with. (And also because it's the honest thing to do.) If this isn't for a class assignment, then could you explain why you need the function to take either 1 or 2 arguments?

Comment: This is just a practical exercise from functional programming module.

Comment: @LioxaZAICHIK FP languages are expression based, they always return something, your `if` expression returns 0 or -1, and throws away the reversed lines in the true branch. Hence you get an `ignore` warning. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's better to show some example code (even if it doesn't work). In its most simplistic form the following function will do what you want:

```
open System
open System.IO
let reverseLines f =
  File.ReadAllLines f
  |> Seq.rev
```

Regarding taking on optional parameters, I believe this should better be done via a CLI library, like [Argu](https://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/), that should handle the other arguments to `tac` as well.

**Edit:**

I just changed the reverse function to `Array.rev` because that's easier to deal with in this case.

There are two parts to this program, you can see that `reverseLines` is essentially unchanged. Then in the `main` we check how many arguments there are and extract the file name into `fName`. In the second part we call directly `File.exists` on the file name and if it's `true` we run reverseLines, and pipe the output into the Console.

You can just run this program as `.\lineReverser.exe C:\tmp\FileToBeReversed.txt`. In case you are just testing in an fsx file just factor out the main into another function and it will work exactly the same.

Everything else in the first part of the answer still stands, some good books on F# include: [Expert F# 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484207416), [Get Programming with F#](https://www.manning.com/books/get-programming-with-f-sharp). And if you just go through the intro Series parts of [fsharpforfunandprofit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) that will clear up many questions you might have.

```
module SOAnswers171016
open System
open System.IO

let reverseLines f =
  File.ReadAllLines f
  |> Array.rev

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let fName = //check how many arguments are passed and extract the filename if there is only one argument 
        match argv.Length with
        | 0 -> failwith "Please specify a file name!"
        | 1 -> argv.[0]
        | _ -> failwith "Too many parameters!"  //you could handle the two file parameter case here 

    match File.Exists(fName) with
    | true -> reverseLines fName |> Array.iter Console.WriteLine //we are just piping the reversed lines to the console
    | false -> failwith "File doesn't exist!"

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: This approach gives me an ignore message, and does not do any action with the text on the file

Comment: Can you show your code? Just edit your original message.

Comment: @LioxaZAICHIK see my Edit.